# Create user defined data type in sql server 2008 that is based on INT IDENTITY(#,#)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Does anyone know whether it is possible to create a UDDT that is something like this:

```
CREATE TYPE dbo.TID FROM int NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1)
```

Everything before IDENTITY(1,1) is legal and will generate a new UDDT. However, I need to set IDENTITY automatically during the definition of UDDT and usage during table definition. Sometimes, in case we decide to change from INT IDENTITY(#,#) to UNIQUEIDENTIFIER I would like to change it in one place only. I don't find it very interesting going through the tables and modifying from one type to another especially because there will be a lot of tables.

Regards,

Huske

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible. Have a look at [CREATE TYPE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175007.aspx). Identity is not part of the data type. It is part of a column definition.

Comment: I was looking at `CREATE TYPE` and secretly hoped that something like this was possible. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

No. IDENTITY property attached to the table too, not just the column

You may not find it interesting, but this is how SQL works

- Not all tables require a surrogate key
- Some tables will require tinyint or smallint or bigint
- If you need UNIQUEIDENTIFIER, use it now (and take the clustered index hit)
- Do you have an actual need *right now*?